# How can I read the properties of an audio file in Objective-C for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, bitrate

How can I get the properties of an audio file (like the number of channels, sample rate and bit rate) programmatically in Objective-C for iOS?

Comment: What kind of audio file?

Comment: it can be any audio file[Compressed, Uncompressed].. for example "sample.wav" or "sample.mp3" audio file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the properties for any audio filetype that is supported on iOS, load the audio data into an [`AVAudioPlayer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) and examine its properties (in particular, the `settings` dictionary).

Comment: Can this be used to read audio from the ipod library? looks like ony the AVPlayer class can be used for that. If I use AVAudioPlayer I can't play the file or get anything from the settings dictionary.